# gitignore syntax to ignore other git repositories?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

I have a git repo full of scripts. When I work on the scripts, I usually cd into the repository directory and do my editing/execution. But I also clone other git repos with test data in them, which then end up on my local machine as subfolders of the first git repo.

However, sometimes I unthinkingly/accidentally git add and/or commit these other git repos. Git knows that they're git repositories, because it scolds me when I stage them.

Easy to unstage/revert, so no harm done. However, this is annoying. I've read the gitignore docs, but I'm not seeing anything obvious - is there a way to configure git to ignore other git repositories automatically?

I've added some paths to .gitignore that cover like ~80% of the repository names, but I'd like something foolproof, if possible.

Comment: Have you already checked Git Submodules? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @DumitruCeban - Those include a repo in another repo. I want to do the opposite of that (block repos from being included in this one accidentally.)

Comment: The `.gitignore` file is a simple list of patterns; there is no way to predict the file name of the repos you might clone into the current directory. So no, no obvious mechanism. The simple solution is "don't do that then"; probably learn to clone into the parent directory.

Comment: Just add a fake submodule in a directory, let's say, `rnd-scripts`, and put your tryout scripts there. Parent repo doesn't track changes within its submodules, it only tracks its own working tree.